# how can I tag a specific resource in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I want to generate a swagger file tagged in ballerina. how can I do that? how can i tag a specific resource function in ballerina?

I checked @openapi:resourceconfig {tag} -> but its not there anymore. I tried to look at the documentation but it only shows to add and exclude tag in the main service but not for the specific tags.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to generate a swagger contract file only for a subset of resource functions in your Ballerina service, the tool currently does not provide that capability.

The `@openapi:ServiceInfo{}` annotation support we have at the service level to add and exclude tags is used in conjunction with the OpenAPI validator tool, to selectively validate your Ballerina service against operations with specific tags in the Swagger contract. More details about this annotation can be found in the [official Ballerina documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/openapi-tool/#annotation-reference).

A feature request has been created to address this requirement, which you can track [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/openapi-tools/issues/1527)

In the meantime, you can consider the below workarounds

1. **Separate Services:**
   Move the resources you need into a separate service (which can still
   be attached to the same listener). Then, use the following command
   to selectively generate the contract only for that particular
   service:

   ```bash
   bal openapi -i <ballerina-resource-file> [-s|--service] <service-name>
   ```
2. **Post-processing Swagger File:**
   Write a script to post-process the generated Swagger file and filter
   out the unwanted resources based on your criteria.